# Android database

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my situation-- I created a registration activity that will accept user's data and store it in a table. After registering, user is directed to a confirmation page wherein he will be shown his/her memberid which is randomly generated. Now, i want to associate this number to the particular person who registered and save his name and password(which is stored in register table along with other details) along with memberid in a new table so that i can then login. Can you guys help me with this.

Comment: just retrieve the values from the old table in a cursor, use them to insert them in the new table? You know the logic, you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: ya vinay.. if you could do dat... it will help me

Comment: Well, someone will help you with that(I won't). But a piece of advice : when you want to do something, and you KNOW what to do, break down the problem into parts, and look for the solution to every sub-problem by yourself. You will never 'learn' if you go around 'asking' for a 'complete' working solution to your problems. For eg: learn how to retrieve values (look for `rawquery()`, `Cursors`) and then how to add data to another table(look for `execSql()` ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe Cursor to get all the details you want from the database.

```
Database db = new Database(this);   

 Cursor yourdata = db.getDetails(this);
if(yourdata!=null)
{
yourdata.moveToFirst();
String value= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(yourUserName); 
String value= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(yourpassword);
}
```

And then create a new Table as you like just insert the retrieval record in to the new Table with your random generated id.

OR

Instead of creating new Table you can just Alter the main table to add your random generated id. It saves memory.

**EDIT:**

```
 public void updateMemberid(int memberid, int primarykeyid)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String where = PRIMARYKEYIDCOLUMNNAME+"="+primarykeyid; 
    values.put(MEMBERIDCOLUMN, memberid);
    db.update(YOUTABLE, values, where, null);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: u mean to say i should update the register table with the column memberid??

Comment: yes.. Add column Memberid Column to your register table and update your table base on primary key or unique key..

Comment: k.. with update i can add column to the table.. but wat about the memberid dat is displayed in textview. how will i add dat id at da same tym...??